# Что такое Mock и Stub? И как их правильно применять?

Tags: тестирование, mocking

Есть такие понятия как mock & stub. Я не могу понять, зачем и как их использовать. Как я могу заменить например объект из базы данных моком и при этом так сказать оттестить функцию, которая берет данные из базы данных? как это вообще возможно?
если можно напишите примеры использования моков и стабов кодом. можно на C#, javascript, C++, да хоть на псевдоязыке

Comment: Вам не нужно тестить получение объекта из бд, вам нужно тестить свою бизнес логику. ORM сама-то покрыта тестами. А объекты в ваших тестах вы подменяете фейковыми.

Comment: @tcpack4, как это не нужно. мне же нужно знать, что функция GetRecords() получает правильные данные из базы. Вот например, мне надо протестировать функцию, которая берет из базы данных всех с именем Коля. Я пишу функцию, в ней пишу что-то типа var kolias=Context.People.Where(name=>name="Коля"). Теперь мне надо протестировать, действительно ли из базы берутся Коли, а не Надежды.

Comment: @Adventurer вы не поняли суть Юнит теста . Если прямо использовать логику и базу это уже называется интеграционный Тест. Юнит тест - это модули тест. детально Прочитайте Что такое Юнит тесты . https://habrahabr.ru/post/169381/  http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2014/05/unit-testthe-definition.html

Comment: @Rasul, спасибо, уже догадалась)